# What will happen after my Google App Engine app reach free quota limit (billing is disabled)?

Tags: google-app-engine

What happens if app deployed to GAE reach free quote limit (in case billing disabled)? Google will charge you for using resources above free quote  or your app will become unavailable until free quota will be reset or billing will be enabled ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Google App Engine documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#When_a_Resource_is_Depleted), Google will not charge you, they will disable the depleted resource.

Answer (score 2):

You will see some kind of default 500 Server Error page with Google's Robot image.

Or you can build a custom static HTML error page as well, refer to the docs on configuring  app.yaml -> custom error response

Even if billing is enabled, since you can set a daily budget, the above still stands when your budget is reached. Google say they will never charge anything above the budget you set.